# Which one is right way to write Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

Belows are very simple code to practice Makefile.
Blue box is source code, and red box is Makefile.
I wonder which one is right way to write Makefile btn upper Makefile or bottm Makefile. Yes, I'd like to know "dependecy on header file(helpMe.h)". Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Both are wrong, because you can write a `'%.o:'` rule and make it generic, instead of writing a rule for each source file, and of course you would want to recompile when the header changes, so what is the actual question?

Comment: What?? why.. T_T. The goal is to just create helpMe.o and HeaderTest.o

Comment: Now, but what if you had more source files you would like to compile?

Comment: just .. add?... I'm make virgin, and these are what makefile is in "Headfirst C"..

Comment: I just want to know whether HeaderTest.o depend on helpMe.h or not

Comment: It doesn't depend on it *as-such* but it does want to be re-compiled when it changes. So the top makefile sample is the more correct of the two.

Comment: Try to avoid posting screenshots. You could've easily cut and paste the two examples makefiles as text into your question making them much easier for us to read. There's no reason to include the C source code on the left in your question, whether as a screenshot or text. You can just describe which header files each `.c` file includes.

Answer (score 0):

You do need the `.h` in the object file rule because when the header file changes you will want to recompile of course, so this is a `Makefile` that takes care of that

```
CC      = gcc
LDFLAGS =
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -pedantic
OBJ     = helpMe.o

executable-name: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    @rm -fv *.o executable-name
```

and you can add object files as you wish by just adding the name of the file to the `$(OBJ)` variable, like this

```
CC      = gcc
LDFLAGS =
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -pedantic
OBJ     = helpMe.o HeaderTest.o

executable-name: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    @rm -fv *.o executable-name
```

Comment: This won't work because `helpMe.o` doesn't actually depend on `helpMe.h` and neither does `HeaderTest.o` depend on `HeaderTest.h`. Only `HeaderTest.o` depends on `helpMe.h` and nothing depends on `HeaderTest.h` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RossRidge all that you said, doesn't matter, if you `touch HeaderTest.h` and then run `make` then the target will be updated because the file was created, so it is a dependency that is ignored in case it doesn't exist, so what do you think? Besides, it's not a one to one dependency thing, if any of the files change, the whole thing gets updated.

Comment: `HeaderTest.h` doesn't exist, `touch HeaderTest.h` would needlessly create it as an a empty file. Your makefile does create a one to one dependency between each `.o` file and a `.c` and `.h` file with the same base name. This is your mistake.  If `helpMe.h` changes then your makefile won't rebuild `HeaderTest.o` as required. Instead it will unnecessarily rebuild `helpMe.o` even though `helpMe.c` doesn't actually include `helpMe.h`. You don't seem to understand what your makefile actually does nor do you seem to understand the original poster's question.

Comment: @RossRidge I do understand what the Makefile does, and you are right.